# How to add launch.json for debugging config of a single project in a VS Code workspace?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have a workspace open in VS Code with multiple nested subdirectories for different projects. When I go to the Debugging `Run` in the sidebar and click on **create a launch.json file** a popup prompt appears to **Select a workspace folder to create a launch.json file in or add it to the workspace config file** with the options in the dropdown being the 1. current open workspace 2. *workspace*. When I select (1) and add the required configurations to the `launch.json` file  the `.vscode/launch.json` is located in the root directory of the workspace and **NOT** the root directory of the project (in this case a React Native project) and when running the debugger I get the following error:

> An error occurred while attaching debugger to the application. Seems to be that you are trying to debug from within directory that is not a React Native project root.
> If so, please, follow these instructions: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-react-native#customization (error code 604) (error code 1410)

How can I configure the `launch.json` file for a specific project in a VS Code workspace, rather than for the entire workspace?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you can create a `.vscode` folder in each project manually, and add your `launch.json` there for each project.  Perhaps I misunderstand your question though?

Comment: the issue remains, as in the Debugger menu it does not pick up that you are currently working on a given project in the workspace, so it does not see that `workspace_dir/project_dir/.vscode/launch.json` file

Comment: `.vscode` in a subfolder is not recognized by VSC. Use **MultiRoot Workspace**

Answer (score 4):

You can work with a MultiRoot Workspace.

- Open a Workspace with: **File** | **Open Folder**
- Add Workspaces with: **File** | **Add Folder to Workspace**
- Save the MultiRoot Workspace: **File** | **Save Workspace As**

Next time you open this MultiRoot Workspace with: **File** | **Open Workspace**

Now each Workspace folder can have its own `.vscode` folder with `launch.json` and `tasks.json`.

When you now open a `launch.json` you can add Configurations by hand or with the `Add Configuration...` button in the lower right.

In the Debug Bar you can now select a Launch config from any of the Workspaces.

It is also possible to add the different launch configurations for the sub folders of a Workspace, in case you need to launch multiple configs (server and client) but then you need to set the parameters yourself like `cwd`.

Comment: I already have a vs code workspace with multiple projects in it, the issue is opening that workspace and selecting a project at any moment to debug.

Comment: @AgentAnon Create `.vscode/launch.json` and add your configs needed, then select the one you want from the drop down in Debug Bar. Read the doc on VSC Debugging

Comment: I did create a `.vscode/launch.json` file in the root dir of the project, and I cannot select the config whilst the workspace is open, only when I open the project dir itself. Is there a difference between a `code-workspace` and a MultiRoot Workspace?

Comment: If your projects were set up as multi-roots properly then this extension might be of interest: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.launch-config  You can launch any debug config from any root folder.

Comment: `code-workspace` === MultiRoot Workspace. It depends how many folders you have specified in this `code-workspace` file, use a different editor to open this json file. It can be 1 or more

Answer (score 0):

Add C# extension from Microsoft. Post that open any cs file. It will install C# dependencies.The you will get a pop up
[image]

Click yes. Both tasks.json and launch .json are created.